# Method Overloading and Default Parameters, any other option in Delphi ?

Tags: delphi

I get a  set  numbers  like A, B, C, D  in my program ,  sometimes I need to calc the sum of several of theses  numbers like :

```
    function DoIt2 (a, b : Integer) : Integer ; overload
    begin
        result := a +b ; 
    end;


    function DoIt3 (a, b, c : Integer) : Integer ; overload
    begin
        result := a +b +c  ; 
    end;
```

there are many DoIt's function involved in my problem. I can not use e.g. a IntegerList as I need to Know what has been A and B and so on .....
Any good solution compared to endless function overloading ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use an [open array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_%28Delphi%29#Open_Array_Parameters):

```
function Sum(const Values: array of Integer): Integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for i := low(Values) to high(Values) do
    Result := Result + Values[i];
  end;
end;
```

And call it like this, using an [open array constructor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Calling_Procedures_and_Functions#Open_Array_Constructors):

```
x := Sum([1, 2]);
y := Sum([1, 2, 3]);
z := Sum([42, 666, 29, 1, 2, 3]);
i := Sum([x, y, z]);
```

and so on.

In fact, you'll find this very function (names [`SumInt`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.SumInt) for the integer version), and many similar, already implemented in the `Math` unit.